# Get imagejpeg to display properly

Tags: php, image, jpeg

Is there anyway I can use this to display an image without having to save it?

```
imagejpeg( $thumb, NULL, 100 );
```

This just produces strange characters on the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Content-Type header properly for this to work:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set header for it

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg( $thumb, NULL, 100 );
```

(assuming you know all parameters of imagejpeg)

Answer (score 0):

```
$thumb = imagecreatefromjpeg($url);
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($thumb);
imagedestroy($thumb);
```

The above should work.
If You doing this in framework you should disable layout.