# PHP images: imagepng gives strange results

Tags: php, image, file, header, png

I am generating an image using the imagepng method in PHP using the following code. This solution [Get imagejpeg to display properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327734/get-imagejpeg-to-display-properly) provides insight into the header that must be set. Please see the code below, instead of displaying an image, image data is displayed in text form.

Code:

```
<?php

$img = imagecreatetruecolor(50, 50);
$new_pixel = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 0, 0);
imagesetpixel($img, 25 , 25 , $new_pixel);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($map_img); 
imagedestroy($map_img);

?>
```

Browser Result (not exactly this but similar):

```
�PNG


IHDR1
KP�IDAT8���K
� Eѫ�������(�V�*��EF�@a�
k�tJ�.]���} hh9��&M.z޻4\J`����8�m@�k�П��g��⼺ӀrHw//���,
���zuom�H�� 7�=ʫ��I?�-/W��IEND�B`�
```

One solution suggests using the php file as an image source as such.

```
<img src="generate.php" />
```

But I find this highly impractical for my needs.

Thanks in advance!